# xdt transform fails on HTML file on P tag

Tags: html, msbuild, transform, xdt-transform

I am trying to apply a transform to an HTML file.  The transform works correctly with divs and spans but as soon as I insert a P tag it will fail.

The HTML file I am transforming is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>STREAM Interactive - UAT</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  </head>
    <body>
          <p>my para</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The transform file is very simple:

```
<html xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
   <head>
     <title xdt:Transform="Replace">TITLEHEADINGHERE</title>
   </head>  

</html>
```

The project file that is used to do the transform is:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Dll"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceFile>web.config</SourceFile>
        <TransformFile>web.debug.config</TransformFile>
        <OutputFile>final.config</OutputFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="GenerateConfigs">
        <Message Text="Beginning Transformation." />
        <Message Text="$(SourceFile)" />
        <TransformXml Source="$(SourceFile)" Transform="$(TransformFile)" Destination="$(OutputFile)" />
        <Message Text="Completed Transformation." />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

The command used is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml /p:SourceFile="C:\temp\buildTest\BlueZone\2.3.10.5\PublishedClickOnce\index.html" /p:TransformFile="D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\TransformTemplates\clickonce.index.transform.temp" /p:OutputFile="C:\temp\buildTest\BlueZone\2.3.10.5\PublishedClickOnce\index.html.temp"
```

The  output / error I get is:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.269]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 02/07/2012 10:54:33.
Project "D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-    transform-Template.xml" on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateConfigs:
  Beginning Transformation.
  C:\temp\buildTest\BlueZone\2.3.10.5\PublishedClickOnce\index.html
  Transforming Source File:     C:\temp\buildTest\BlueZone\2.3.10.5\PublishedClickOnce\index.html
  Transformation succeeded
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018: The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-    Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-    Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
Done Building Project "D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml" (default target) (1) ->
(GenerateConfigs target) -> 
  D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018: The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
D:\SAM\SAMSite\bin\msbuild-transform-Template.xml(13,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.09
```

The HTML has been stripped down to the barest possible, previously there have been div's and spans in there.  Interestingly, if I gave the P tag a class it works.

I have no idea why this would be the case.

**EDIT**

As per @Kieren's suggestion I have tried to run using the TransformXml directly.  I get a new error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlAttributePreservationDict.ReadPreservationInfo(String elementStartTag)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlAttributePreservationProvider.GetDictAtPosition(Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.XmlFileInfoElement..ctor(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlFileInfoDocument document)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.CreateElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.LoadFromTextReader(TextReader textReader)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.LoadFromFileName(String     filename)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.Load(String filename)
   at QuickTests.TestTransformXml.OpenSourceFile(String sourceFile) in C:\Users\jon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\QuickTests\QuickTests\TestTransformXmlTask.cs:line 140
```

Comment: just to confirm the paths are all correct as I can remove the P from the file and run the same command and it all works.

Comment: double checked with http://html5.validator.nu/ that the HTML is valid, (had a feeling it might be namespace or something, wanted to ensure it is at least correct html).

Comment: See the source to Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll: an XmlException must be being thrown; then this code is executed: `Uri uri = new Uri(ex.SourceUri);` but, as XmlException documentation indicates, `SourceUri` can be `null`.  Microsoft's bug in their error logging means the exception is going to be tricky to track down!  Maybe the Reflector VS addin will let you attach to msbuild.exe, step through and debug that `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml` method.

Comment: And from that we can establish that there's an `XmlException` being thrown, at least

Comment: You could also recreate the `TransformXml` class yourself based on reflected code: it looks pretty simple and uses a `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlTransformation` object, which is a public class you could reference and call yourself

Comment: OK, so adding a whitespace character after the P (before the greater than symbol <p > works fine.  doing a little test... XmlTransformableDocument xmlTransformableDocument = new XmlTransformableDocument();
                xmlTransformableDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;
                xmlTransformableDocument.Load(sourceFile);
                result = xmlTransformableDocument;  so turning off preserve white space fixes it. no idea how to do this in msbuild yet.

Comment: I have added this as a bug on MS, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752279/msbuild-tansform-failure-for-elements-with-only-one-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the bug report I filed this has now been fixed.  Assuming it will be included in the next release of MsBuild, (don't know when that will be):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752279/msbuild-tansform-failure-for-elements-with-only-one-character